# Android custom share issue

Tags: java, android

> Hi, I am trying to fetch all the applications available in the phone &
>   display them in a grid layout. Basically a custom layout to show
>   applications that can be used to share. I am able to do this, but when
>   I click on gmail or any other app, it crashes my application saying
>   have you mentioned this application in your manifest? I am in need of
>   your help here!!

```
Exception:



android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.gm/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-24 13:03:19.725 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1885)
12-24 13:03:19.725 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1579)
12-24 13:03:19.725 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3934)
12-24 13:03:19.725 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:657)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3894)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:644)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4221)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4189)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at hornok.gmaps.view.activities.TemplateActivity.invokeApplication(TemplateActivity.java:203)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at hornok.gmaps.view.activities.TemplateActivity.access$000(TemplateActivity.java:44)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at hornok.gmaps.view.activities.TemplateActivity$1.onClick(TemplateActivity.java:182)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
12-24 13:03:19.726 9987-9987/hornok.gmaps W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Code:

```
  List<String> packages;
    HashSet<String> stringsHS;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    List<LinearLayout> linearLayoutList;

    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                customViews();
            }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        public void customViews() {

            stringsHS = new HashSet<>();
            packages = new ArrayList<String>();
            linearLayoutList = new ArrayList<>();

            Intent shareIntent=new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            final List<ResolveInfo> resInfosNew=new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
            final List<ResolveInfo> resInfos=context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
            resInfosNew.addAll(resInfos);
            if(!resInfos.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Have package");
                int count=0;
                for (ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos) {
                    String packageName=resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    /*if(packageName.contains("com.facebook.katana")){
                        resInfosNew.remove(count);
                    }else
                        packages.add(packageName);*/
                    packages.add(packageName);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            stringsHS.addAll(packages);
            packages.clear();
            packages.addAll(stringsHS);

            Log.d(TAG, "packages_list "+packages.size());

            double packagelength = packages.size();
            double colLength = 4;

            double actualVal = packagelength/colLength;
            int simpleVal = packages.size() / 4;

            if(actualVal > simpleVal){
                simpleVal = simpleVal + 1;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "simpleVal :: "+simpleVal+" :: "+actualVal);

            GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(context);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gridLayoutLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            gridLayoutLP.setMargins(getValueInDP(16, context), 0, getValueInDP(16, context), 0);
            gridLayout.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
            gridLayout.setColumnCount(4);/*if(packageName.contains("com.facebook.katana")){
                        resInfosNew.remove(count);
                    }else
                        packages.add(packageName);*/
            gridLayout.setRowCount(simpleVal);

            gridLayout.setColumnOrderPreserved(false);

            for (int i = 0; i <= packages.size()-1; i++) {
                try{
                    LinearLayout shareIntentLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
                    shareIntentLayout.setGravity(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(
                            GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f),
                            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f));

                    shareIntentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    params.setMargins(getValueInDP(16, context), getValueInDP(16, context),
                            getValueInDP(16, context), getValueInDP(16, context));
                    shareIntentLayout.setLayoutParams(params);


                    String pkg = packages.get(i);
                    ApplicationInfo ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(pkg, 0);

                    CharSequence appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(ai);
                    Drawable appIcon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(pkg);

                    ImageView shareImage = new ImageView(context);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams shareImageLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    shareImageLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    shareImage.setBackgroundDrawable(appIcon);
                    shareIntentLayout.addView(shareImage, shareImageLP);

                    TextView appNameTV = new TextView(context);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams appNameLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    appNameLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    appNameLP.setMargins(0, getValueInDP(12, context), 0, 0);
                    appNameTV.setText(appName);
                    appNameTV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 9);
                    appNameTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.hornok_grey));
                    shareIntentLayout.addView(appNameTV, appNameLP);

                    gridLayout.addView(shareIntentLayout, i);
                    linearLayoutList.add(shareIntentLayout);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            nestedScrollView.addView(gridLayout, gridLayoutLP);

            for(int i = 0; i<=linearLayoutList.size()-1; i++){
                final int finalI = i;
                linearLayoutList.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        invokeApplication(packages.get(finalI),resInfosNew.get(finalI));
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        private void invokeApplication(String packageName, ResolveInfo resolveInfo) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Referral");
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Expected result.. it must go to the respective app that is clicked!!

Comment: Have you tried debug? Please share your manifest with us.

Comment: @ZoranBajcer, Hi i found the issue, it is happening because of the way in which I am filtering duplicates using hashset. I have the issue resolved